# Neither Intellij nor VS Code will recognize new, shorter React fragment

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, intellij-idea

I'm new to React, and I'm going over the [latest tutorial](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/tutorial-tic-tac-toe). I've tried running it in Intellij and VS Code, but without any modifications, the tutorial gives me a syntax error about an empty fragment, as shown here:

```
export default function Square() {
  return (
    <>  // unexpected token here
      <button className="square">X</button>
      <button className="square">X</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

I did a bit of research and found that I needed to upgrade Babel, so I did a:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/code-frame
```

That removed the error from within VS Code, but not Intellij, nor the browser itself. I tried to install with a -g also, with the same result. Can anyone help me?

Comment: can't see any errors when using your code snippet in Intellij IDEA; what IDE version do you use?

Comment: I'm using 2022.1.3 Ultimate.